# Import a Postgis raster into a QGIS graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, raster, postgis, qgis-modeler

I'm creating a model using the Graphical Modeler on QGIS (version 3.16.16 - Hannover).
I also have a PostGIS database, with the raster extension installed.

In my model, I use the "Postgres SQL execute SQL" algorithm to merge multiple raster tiles directly in my PostGIS database.

Then I would like to import the resulting merged raster into my model using the "PostgreSQL execute and load SQL" algorithm.

But I can't manage to import the image itself ; only the ID column is imported, as a simple table.
It seems that it doesn't recognize the "raster" format.

The algorithm asks me what is the geometry field in my table.

Do you know if this import tool only works with vector layers?

How can I import a PostGIS raster into my model, in order to process algorithms on it?

[image]